# How to undo git reset --hard to recover lost data?

Tags: git

I have tried to commit my source to github, below is what I have done:

1. git add .
2. git reset --hard

In the first step I add the file that will be commited. But after that I don't want to commit it, and search the way to backout the file added. So I tried to use "git reset --hard".

And the result is all my data has been removed.
Is there anyway to undo 2nd step and recover my data?

Comment: Did you sync with an upstream repo.

Comment: Do you have shadow copies or time machine set up

Comment: Look in the temp folder there may be a copy or partial copy

Comment: In general, if you did not commit or stash, then your work is gone.  If you are using a modern IDE such as IntelliJ, you might be able to retrieve the content from local history.

Comment: You are not out of luck!  See the answer posted below.

Comment: I'm trying the solution below and maybe it can work for me

Answer (score 3):

**I have a solution, if you haven't run `git gc`!**

When you run `git add .` it will create new objects for any files with modified content.  These will show up in `.git/objects/*/*`.

Use this find command to find the most recent changes to your `.git` repo:

```
find .git -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | grep git/objects/../ | sort -n | tail -100
```

You will see an output like this, which is each "blob" that has been added to the git "database" sorted in date order:

```
1555137117.9174205020 Sat 13 Apr 2019 02:31:57 AM EDT .git/objects/27/0e06d22c74316a523a3d5faf1e525730f30063
1555137119.0064516220 Sat 13 Apr 2019 02:31:59 AM EDT .git/objects/d8/dee4a715c2064caee8662dd8ccf5dc612cb90c
1555137120.8755050290 Sat 13 Apr 2019 02:32:00 AM EDT .git/objects/00/02959bbbcd5a170ab04a32093ba8c5abca1089
1555137310.5479249430 Sat 13 Apr 2019 02:35:10 AM EDT .git/objects/c3/a6bbbb091403d18550cc729a98e90a643bfa66
```

Now, all that is left is to extract the content of the objects one at a time until you find what you are after:

Take the `.git/objects/c3/a6bbbb091403d18550cc729a98e90a643bfa66` and extract the object ID from it by combining the `c3` with the `a6bbb...`.  Pass this to `git cat-file`

```
git cat-file -p c3a6bbbb091403d18550cc729a98e90a643bfa66
```

And alas, the content of the file at the point you ran `git add .` will be dumped out to your terminal!  (use bash redirection `>` to write that to a file)

Comment: This should probably be posted as an answer to the nominated duplicate instead. (Though the accepted answer is vaguely similar.)

Comment: Hi sir,
I'm trying to use `git cat-file`, and I can see the content of the file in terminal, but I can not write it to file using `>`. Beside that, in the source I have about 7000 file, so I have to write each file in there by hand ?